# Two kids go back in time by accident

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

There’s this book I remember reading this like 2 or 3 years ago about two kids that accidentally time traveled back in time due to some mistake in a time machine. They just happened to be near the machine at the worst time. I remember the story smoothly going back in forth between the present and the past that the kids were in.

I didn’t get to read much of the book but when the kids were in the past they met some sort of wanderer or merchant maybe. And that person thought they were crazy cause of the way they were dressed and the way they were speaking. Obviously they were foreign.

Scene changes and we’re back with the father and I think they’re panicking wondering where the kids are and they call the cops I think and they get reported missing. All while (well not while but you get what I mean) the kids are traveling with the stranger to the nearest town.

I think this was a trilogy and one of the critique quotes I think compared it to *Harry Potter*. The cover was a nice art animation style cartoonish, friendly (nice to look at).

Comment: What gender were the children?

Answer (score 4):

[The Gideon the Cutpurse trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gideon_Trilogy) by Linda Buckley-Archer.

[image: Gideon the Cutpurse]

> Gideon Seymour, cutpurse and gentleman, hides from the villainous Tar Man. Suddenly the sky peels away like fabric and from the gaping hole fall two curious-looking children. Peter Schock and Kate Dyer have fallen straight from the twenty-first century, thanks to an experiment with an antigravity machine. Before Gideon and the children have a chance to gather their wits, the Tar Man takes off with the machine -- and Kate and Peter's only chance of getting home. Soon Gideon, Kate, and Peter are swept into a journey through eighteenth-century London and form a bond that, they hope, will stand strong in the face of unfathomable treachery.

As for the comparisons with Harry Potter, the second books boasts on its cover:

[image: "May very well give J.K Rowling a run for her money." - School Library Journal]

and the third:

[image: The concluding volume to the trilogy "for kids who love Harry Potter" -EntertainmentWeekly.com]